# Angular 2 Testing error: The component has 1 <ng-content> elements, but only 0 slots were provided

Tags: angular

So I have this *Greeter* component that accept a input string and transcluded content. I got this error "The component has 1 *ng-content* elements, but only 0 slots were provided." when I add in *ng-content* tag. If I remove that, my test will be executed with no error. Here is my code and test code.

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from 'angular2/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'greeter',
  template: `
    <h1>Hello {{name}}!</h1>
    <ng-content></ng-content>  
`
})
export class Greeter {
  @Input() name: string;
}
```

Here is my test code:-

```
import {TestComponentBuilder, ComponentFixture, beforeEachProviders,  beforeEach, inject, describe,
expect, it, injectAsync, setBaseTestProviders } from 'angular2/testing';
import {TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/platform/testing/browser'

import {Greeter} from './noob.component';

describe('Noob: component', () => {
let tcb: TestComponentBuilder;
setBaseTestProviders(TEST_BROWSER_PLATFORM_PROVIDERS, TEST_BROWSER_APPLICATION_PROVIDERS);

beforeEachProviders(() => [
    TestComponentBuilder,
    Greeter
]);

beforeEach(<any>inject([TestComponentBuilder], (_tcb: TestComponentBuilder) => {
    tcb = _tcb;
}));

//specs
it('should render `John Doe!`', (done: any) => {
    tcb.createAsync(Greeter).then((fixture: ComponentFixture) => {
        let greeter = fixture.componentInstance,
            element = fixture.nativeElement;
        greeter.name = 'John Doe';
        fixture.detectChanges(); //trigger change detection
        expect(element.querySelector('h1').innerText).toBe('Hello John Doe!');
        done();
    })
        .catch((e: any) => done.fail(e));
});
})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue is that ng-content is not supported in root level components. When you instantiate the component in isolation in the unit test it becomes a root in that context.

The workaround is to create a simple host component for your component just for the purpose of the test.

```
@Component({
  directives:[Greeter],
  template:'<greeter></greeter>'
})
class GreeterHost{
}
```

Now instantiate `GreeterHost` in the unit test instead so that your ng-content component no longer is a root.

With this approach you can still test greeter, but it will be tested via the new host.