# How to test transcluded content in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angular, unit-testing, testing

While testing an Angular component that has transclusion slots with `<ng-content>`, we have no
explicit means to check if the transcluded content is placed as intended inside the component.
For example:

```
// base-button.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'base-button',
  template: `<button [type]="type">
    <ng-content></ng-content>
  </button>`,
})
export class BaseButtonComponent {
  @Input() type = 'button';
}
```

Basically, when creating a component instance in the spec file, we do this:

```
// base-button.component.spec.ts
it('should reflect the `type` property into the "type" attribute of the button', () => {
  const fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BaseButtonComponent);
  fixture.detectChanges();

  const { componentInstance, nativeElement } = fixture;
  componentInstance.type = 'reset';

  const button = nativeElement.querySelector('button');
  expect(button.type === 'reset');
});
```

We can do this for every property and method of the component, but what about the
transcluded content? A workaround would be creating a host component for test purposes:

```
// base-button.component.spec.ts
...
@Component({
  template: `<base-button>Foo bar</base-button>`
})
export class BaseButtonHostComponent {}
...

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BaseButtonComponent, BaseButtonHostComponent ]
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));

  it('should transclude the content correctly', () => {
    const hostFixture = TestBed.createComponent(BaseButtonHostComponent);
    hostFixture.detectChanges();
    const button = hostFixture.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    expect(button.textContent === 'Foo bar');
  });
...
```

But, as you could imagine, this is rather inconvenient, also because this has to be done
for every component with transcluded content, and possibly for every `<ng-content>` element
in its template. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's indeed a rather obscure way to do it. Basically, `TestBed.createComponent` invokes
the component's factory `create` method, which also supports projectable DOM nodes to be
inserted into transclusion slots.

```
// @angular/core/testing.js
createComponent(component) {
  ...
  const componentFactory = this._compiler.getComponentFactory(component);
  ...
  const componentRef = componentFactory.create(Injector.NULL, [], `#${rootElId}`, this._moduleRef);
  ...
}
```

We have to do the same, and here's the trick:

```
// base-button.component.spec.ts
describe('BaseButtonComponent', () => {
  let factory: ComponentFactory<BaseButtonComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [ BaseButtonComponent ]
    })
    .overrideModule(BrowserDynamicTestingModule, {
      set: {
        entryComponents: [ BaseButtonComponent ]
      }
    })
    .compileComponents();

    const resolver = <ComponentFactoryResolver>TestBed.get(ComponentFactoryResolver, null);
    factory = resolver.resolveComponentFactory(BaseButtonComponent);
  }));

  it('should transclude the provided nodes into the button', () => {
    const tnode = document.createTextNode('Foo bar');
    const componentRef = factory.create(Injector.NULL, [[ tnode ]]);
    const button = componentRef.location.nativeElement.querySelector('button');
    expect(button.textContent === 'Foo bar');
  });
});
```

`TestBed.get` allows us to retrieve the `ComponentFactoryResolver` service. In order to retrieve
the component's factory, though, the component's class must be listed in the module's `entryComponents`
property. The module in question is `BrowserDynamicTestingModule` and `TestBed` exposes a handy
method to alter its properties.

Once you have the factory, the trick is served. The only annoying part is generating all the
projectable nodes by hand, so you can create a utility function for that:

```
function createComponentWithContents(factory, ...contents) {
  const template = document.createElement('template');
  const projectableNodes = contents.map(html => {
    template.innerHTML = html;
    return [ ...template.content.childNodes ];
  });
  return factory.create(Injector.NULL, projectableNodes);
}

const componentRef = createComponentWithContents(factory, '<i class="fa fa-star"></i> Win!');
```

It's a shame that `TestBed.createComponent` doesn't allow to do that right away.

Comment: didn't work for me. I ended up doing like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54748059/1845013